# Timeline: Marker and Keyframe do not have the same "position"(on the frame)

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes, timeline, marker

My issue is that I use markers to switch between cameras. My cameras are animated and my first camera stops at exactly 27.696(I need that for my project). My 2nd camera starts at 27.696 and moves to 55.392 and so on...
And i position the marker exactly on the keyframe but it snaps back to Frame 27(so they don't have the same "position"). That means, that my camera view changes roughly half a frame earlier and that also minimizes the animation length.
[image]

My question is how can I change the markers position precisely?
PS: I moved the keyframes precisely in the graph-editor.

Comment: well, if i understand the docu (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.marker.html#bpy.ops.marker.add) correct, the marker position is saved as int. So you cannot set them on a float value.

Comment: Apart from what @Chris said - since Blender will render this frame by frame, I'm not quite sure why you need them somewhere inbetween frames anyway. But I might just be very nescient.

Comment: well i want to make a "edit". This means that I switch the camera between the frames, so it syncs with the bpm. With my calculations, it would be 27.696 Frames(129.98 BPM and 60FPS)

Comment: But you won't render between two frames, so it doesn't matter to change your camera at a subframe level even if you could. Factually the render would still render the new camera at the next frame regardless.